# How can I see if a page layout is used?

Tags: page-layout

I am currently tidying up my salesforce org, and I wonder if some page layouts are actually used? Is there a way to check that?

Tia.

Answer (score 3):

On the page layouts of an object you should be able to see a button -->  Page layout assignment ( if you are an admin / have customize application privilege)

[image]

When you click on the button, you can see the list of profiles and the page layouts assigned to the profiles. ASAIK this has to be manually done where you need to compare and see if a specific page layout is assigned to a profile, if not its currently not in use.

Comment: of course then you have to see if the Profile has any assigned users  as often the profiles become obsolete

Comment: @Rao How to query which page layouts are used by which profiles